# aws amplify nextjs SSR does not want to refresh

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

I'am testing Amplify **SSR** with NextJS. My local environnement works perfectly : My content is correctly refresh every 60 seconds but when I publish on AWS AMPLIFY (eu-west-2) contents don't want to refesh.

Here the source I used : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/mobile/host-a-next-js-ssr-app-with-real-time-data-on-aws-amplify/

Here are some configuration files :

package.json

```
{
  "name": "poc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-amplify": "^4.0.3",
    "next": "10.2.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from "../aws-exports";
Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });

export default function Home({date}) {

  return (
      <>
        <b>{date}</b>
      </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps(){
  return {
    props: {
      page,
      date:(new Date()).toString()
    },
      revalidate: 60
  }
}
```

aws-exports.js

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-west-2"
};


export default awsmobile;
```

project-config.json

```
{
  "projectName": "monpoc",
  "version": "3.0",
  "frontend": "javascript",
  "javascript": {
    "framework": "react",
    "config": {
      "SourceDir": ".",
      "DistributionDir": "build",
      "BuildCommand": "npm run-script build",
      "StartCommand": "npm run-script start"
    }
  },
  "providers": [
    "awscloudformation"
  ]
}
```

[image: Build complete]

```
2021-06-05T17:48:22.315Z [INFO]: Page                              Size     First Load JS
                                 ┌ ● / (ISR: 60 Seconds)           1.67 kB        64.7 kB
                                 ├   /_app                         0 B              63 kB
                                 ├ ○ /404                          3.06 kB        66.1 kB
                                 └ λ /api/hello                    0 B              63 kB
                                 + First Load JS shared by all     63 kB
                                 ├ chunks/framework.c38115.js    42 kB
                                 ├ chunks/main.71948a.js         19.4 kB
                                 ├ chunks/pages/_app.9e3669.js   571 B
                                 ├ chunks/webpack.189c53.js      994 B
                                 └ css/fb7e07ce64500530d3fc.css  194 B
2021-06-05T17:48:22.315Z [INFO]: λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
                                 ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
                                 ●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
                                 (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
2021-06-05T17:48:23.011Z [INFO]: Done in 14.73s.
2021-06-05T17:48:23.016Z [INFO]: Starting SSR Build...
2021-06-05T17:50:09.606Z [INFO]: SSR Build Complete.
2021-06-05T17:50:10.659Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
2021-06-05T17:50:10.660Z [INFO]: ## Build completed successfully
2021-06-05T17:50:10.661Z [INFO]: # Starting caching...
2021-06-05T17:50:10.759Z [INFO]: Creating cache artifact...
2021-06-05T17:50:14.604Z [INFO]: # Cache artifact is: 238MB
2021-06-05T17:50:14.673Z [INFO]: # Uploading cache artifact...
2021-06-05T17:50:17.098Z [INFO]: # Caching completed
2021-06-05T17:50:17.125Z [INFO]: No custom headers found.
2021-06-05T17:50:17.127Z [INFO]: # Starting build artifact upload process...
2021-06-05T17:50:19.102Z [INFO]: # Build artifact is: 18MB
2021-06-05T17:50:19.116Z [INFO]: # Build artifact is: 18MB
2021-06-05T17:50:19.117Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifactsHash.zip'...
2021-06-05T17:50:19.207Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifacts.zip'...
2021-06-05T17:50:19.531Z [INFO]: # Build artifact upload completed
2021-06-05T17:50:19.532Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2021-06-05T17:50:19.532Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

I get stuck : "Sat Jun 05 2021 17:49:26 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"

SSR mode seems to work but how to get ISR correctly apply

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Were you able to figure anything out?

Comment: Any solution on this. I am stuck for my production deployment. Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For Next v11
The issue is, if you've used revalidate interval from the environment variables, that environment variable is not accessible to the Lamba function. I've observed that if I hard code the revalidate interval, then the page refreshes correctly with ISR.

For Next v9
I did not face this issue for Next v9.